# Graph vanishes if there is no other control on the form

Tags: c#, system.drawing

Here is my code

```
private void graphToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            button1.Visible = false;
            button2.Visible = false;
            button3.Visible = false;
            button4.Visible = false;
            label1.Visible = false;
            textBox1.Visible = false;
            textBox2.Visible = false;
            textBox3.Visible = false;
            textBox4.Visible = false;
            textBox5.Visible = false;
            textBox6.Visible = false;
            textBox7.Visible = false;
            textBox8.Visible = false;
            textBox9.Visible = false;
            textBox10.Visible = false;
            label2.Visible = false;
            label3.Visible = false;
            label4.Visible = true;
            gg = this.CreateGraphics();
            p3 = new Pen(Color.Blue,5);
            b1 = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);
            p2 = new Pen(Color.Red);
            Font f=new Font("Arial",16);
            float ox = this.ClientSize.Width / 2;
            float oy = this.ClientSize.Height / 2;
            gg.DrawLine(p3, ox - 500, oy, ox + 500, oy);
            gg.DrawLine(p3, ox, oy + 300, ox, oy - 300);
            gg.DrawString("Argument", f, b1, ox - 100, oy - 200);
            gg.DrawString("<----f(Argument)---->", f, b1, ox + 100, oy + 100);
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            {
                double tem1 = graphValuesCal();
                double temp2 = functionCal();
                gg.FillEllipse(b1, ox + (float)tem1/2,oy-20*(float)temp2, (float)5, (float)5);
                Thread.Sleep(10);
            }

        }
```

when i run this code the graph is plotted but when the loop completes the graph as well as the the strings and lines(axis) vanish. If i comment out this code

```
                button1.Visible = false;
                button2.Visible = false;
                button3.Visible = false;
                button4.Visible = false;
                label1.Visible = false;
                textBox1.Visible = false;
                textBox2.Visible = false;
                textBox3.Visible = false;
                textBox4.Visible = false;
                textBox5.Visible = false;
                textBox6.Visible = false;
                textBox7.Visible = false;
                textBox8.Visible = false;
                textBox9.Visible = false;
                textBox10.Visible = false;
                label2.Visible = false;
                label3.Visible = false;
```

means if all these controls were visible before then they would remain visible when i click the `Graph menu` item. Then the lines and the graph does not vanish
There may be something basic here but i think i am missing that one.
Help needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're drawing should be done in an `OnPaint` event method.

On your form adhere to the `OnPaint` event and add your painting to that method, something like this:

```
// Put this in your constructor, or use VisualStudio to create the method for you
this.Paint += new System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventHandler(this.paint_Method);

private void paint_Method(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{ 
     gg = e.Graphics;
     p3 = new Pen(Color.Blue,5);
     b1 = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);
     p2 = new Pen(Color.Red);
     Font f=new Font("Arial",16);
     float ox = this.ClientSize.Width / 2;
     float oy = this.ClientSize.Height / 2;
     gg.DrawLine(p3, ox - 500, oy, ox + 500, oy);
     gg.DrawLine(p3, ox, oy + 300, ox, oy - 300);
     gg.DrawString("Argument", f, b1, ox - 100, oy - 200);
     gg.DrawString("<----f(Argument)---->", f, b1, ox + 100, oy + 100);
     for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
     {
         double tem1 = graphValuesCal();
         double temp2 = functionCal();
         gg.FillEllipse(b1, ox + (float)tem1/2,oy-20*(float)temp2, 5f, 5f);
         // Thread.Sleep(10);
     }
}
```

You probably want to call `this.Invalidate()` as well within your `graphToolStripMenuItem_Click` method, and bear in mind that the code I moved here should be removed from that method.

Comment: Can you please provide some example or point me to some usefull link? i am trying but still not working

Answer (score 2):

Don't draw in your menu click.  Instead, `Invalidate()` and draw in the subsequent `OnPaint` override.